# Place top answers above top questions in Stack Exchange network profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile, top-questions, top-answers

From [Jeff Atwood:](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

> In March 2010, we rebalanced our reputation system to favor answers.

In all my sites' profile pages, my top answers are placed above the questions.  But in the Stack Exchange network profile, top questions are listed above your top answers.

My request:  If answers are favored over questions, and since this is the way with the other site profiles, can we have the network profile page rejiggered so that answers are shown first?  I would actually prefer this over the current way.

What do y'all think of it?